# How do I instantiate class with dependency injection in .net core 5 or 6?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

In a .net core 5 or 6 api, if I have a dependency:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency>((svc) =>
{
    return new MyDependency(appSettings.ConnectionStrings.MyDB);
});
```

and I have a class that uses the dependency:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate the class so that the dependency is injected into the constructor?  In a controller, this is done for me when the controller is instantiated.  How do I do it for my own classes?

I can use services.GetServices explicitly, but I think that is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

Call to

```
ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(IServiceProvider provider, params object[] parameters)
```

from the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-activatorutilities-createinstance-1(system-iserviceprovider-system-object()))

Answer (score 1):

> I can use services.GetServices explicitly, but I think that is frowned
> upon.

Yes, this is the documented way to do it:

> Services and their dependencies within an ASP.NET Core request are
> exposed through `HttpContext.RequestServices`.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-services)
`HttpContext.RequestServices` is of type `IServiceProvider` which offers the `GetService` method.

But it is also adviced not to do it:

> Avoid using the service locator pattern. For example, don't invoke
> GetService to obtain a service instance when you can use DI instead

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

This won't be done by default. If you are trying to use something that is injected into the request pipeline, you would have to pass that injected value in the controller and pass it on to the constructor.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMyDependency _dependency;
    
    public HomeController(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
    
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass(_dependency);
        ....
    
        return View(myclass.stuff);
    }
```

Comment: ok thanks.  I thought maybe there was a function within the framework that you could tell it to instantiate a type and it would handle the injection.  I guess that functionally is only internal to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class and its dependencies to the service collection, then inject it into your methods or use the IServiceProvider GetRequiredService

eg.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
services.AddScoped<MyClass>()
...

    [Route("home")]
    public IActionResult Index([FromServices]MyClass myClass)
    {
       var result = myClass.DoStuff();
       ....

       return View(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet).

At startup of your app, add:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddIGet();
```

Then get `IGet i` via dependency injection and use it like this:

```cs
var myClass = i.Get<MyClass>();
```

All the dependencies in the constructor of `MyClass` have been injected into `myClass`. Make sure that all those dependencies are available in the serviceCollection or remove some of the dependencies from the constructor.

Note that MyClass need NOT be added to the serviceCollection.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

First: Create a container singleton class (not injected) for injected Services

```cs
public class InjectedServices
{
    public static InjectedServices instance { get; } = new InjectedServices();
    public IServiceProvider ApplicationServices { set; private get; }
    
    public T getTransient<T>(IServiceScope scope) 
    {
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
        return service;
    }
    public IServiceScope CreateScope()
    {
        return ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
    }
}
```

Second: Load services in my class from Startup.cs

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    ...
              
    //Load Injected class in InjectedServices
    InjectedServices.instance.ApplicationServices = app.ApplicationServices;
}
```

Third: Consume everywhere:

```cs
using (IServiceScope scope = InjectedServices.instance.CreateScope())
{
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass)InjectedServices.instance.getTransient<MyClass>(scope);
    myClass.methodOfMyClass();
}
```